# На стыке союзов -- в чем разница?

Tags: союзов

У Розенталя в § 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов: Я думаю, что, когда заключённые увидят лестницу, многие захотят бежать (М.Г.) – запятая разделяет подчинительные союзы что и когда.

Но в "Русской грамматике" в § 3117:

Известно, что когда поезд набирает скорость, вагон меньше трясет.

Почему после *что* нет запятой после *что*?

Answer (score 2):

doom, Вы не вдумались в § 3117, там всё объясняется.

http://rusgram.narod.ru/3108-3135.html

Там разбираются  ВИДЫ СЕМАНТИЧЕСКИХ ОСЛОЖНЕНИЙ СОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОЙ
СВЯЗИ.

В отличие от предложений собственно соединительных сложносочиненные предложения, осложненные значением очередности или обусловленности,

во-первых, характеризуются необратимостью частей;

во-вторых, при включении в состав неэлементарной сложной конструкции части таких предложений оказываются неравнозначными;

ср.: Я позвонила, и мне тотчас отворила дверь пожилая служанка и: Я помню, что когда я позвонила, то мне тотчас отворила дверь пожилая служанка; Поезд набирает скорость, и вагон меньше трясет и: Известно, что когда поезд набирает скорость, вагон меньше трясет. Части неравнозначны, первая часть более значительна, на неё падает логическое ударение, поэтому её нельзя убрать из предложения без потери смысла.Следовательно, и запятой после "что" нет.

Comment: Но ведь в структурном отношении изъятие возможно?Ср. у Розенталя: (запятая ставится) ***Григорий, обожжённый внезапной и радостной решимостью, с трудом удержал коня и, когда последняя сотня, едва не растоптав Степана, промчалась мимо, подскакал к нему (Ш.)*** —               **при изъятии придаточной части с союзом когда значение предложно-именного сочетания к нему становится неясным, но в структурном отношении такое изъятие возможно, поэтому запятая между сочинительным и подчинительным союзами в подобных случаях обычно ставится.**

Comment: @Людмила, Это то все правильно, части не равнозначны. Но в правиле (если брать Розенталя) нет прямого упоминания, что это как-то повлияет на пунктуацию. И "Грамота" (в очередной раз) тоже все примитивно излагает, по формальному признаку. Как правило-то сформулировать, чтобы сеять все вопросы, подобные этому?

Comment: Вопросы не снимутся, потому что нюансов всегда много, а чувствующий язык человек будет ставить знаки препинания не по справочникам, а по смыслу, вкладываемому им в предложение. Потому и расхождения. Один так чувствует, другой по-другому. Наверно, это правильно. А вот тот, кто учится грамоте, пусть следует правилам строго.

Comment: Боюсь, что Вы меня опять не поняли. Я именно и прошу сформулировать правило строго. Так, чтобы там было упоминание неравнозначных частей, если это критично, и не было бы ничего лишнего. Вот тогда вопросы, связанные, с "разными чувствами" и исчезнут. Не хочу пальцами показывать, но ясно же что разговоры об ошибке в РГ порождены именно буквоедским подходом к написанному у Розенталя (или еще где), а совсем не "чувствами". А РГ при всех разговорах о неравнозначности частей правила (во всяком случае - в том параграфе) нету. Отсюда и недопонимание и мнение об "ошибке в учебниках".

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в параграфе 3117. И в учебниках, и в словарях такое случается, увы.

Есть два случая неразделения *что когда*: придаточное начинается с

а) то,

б) тогда.

См.: [Постановка запятой при встрече союзов](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188).

Comment: *Есть два случая неразделения что когда: придаточное начинается с а) то, б) тогда.* - нет таких случаев. Одно придаточное (внешнее) здесь начинается  с "что", второе, внутреннее  - с "когда". Ваша постоянная неряшливость в изложении мыслей опять очень режет глаза. Ну а что до ошибок - да, они случаются. Но РГ - источник выверенный вдоль и поперек.  Да т объяснение отсутствию той запятой есть у Розенталя.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая там действительно дискуссионна. Но я бы не сводил все к простой ошибке.
Логика человека, запятую ту не поставившего мне лично понятно. Другое дело, что он может быть неправ.

У Розенталя (Книга: Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация) в том самом 36-м параграфе есть оговорка, более полная чем её приводит G. A.
Критерием необходимости запятой Розенталь называет возможность изъятия внутреннего придаточного без нарушения цельности фразы. И далее:

> Однако не всегда такая несложная операция может быть проделана.

http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/48854

Так вот, если изъять "когда поезд набирает скорость" фраза становится малопонятно. ***Известно, что вагон меньше трясет***. Без контекста такую фразу нельзя признать осмысленной. "Меньше" требует пояснения - "меньше чем что или" "меньше чем когда".

Кстати, в Нацкорпусе есть огромное число примеров без запятой на стыке "что" и "когда", что никак возможностью изъятия внутреннего придаточного не мотивировано. Больше всего поражает наличие двух разных подходов в одном тексте, т.е. одним автором написанном и одним корректором проверенном. Вот например.

> Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)   [омонимия снята] Все примеры (2)
>   После войны из документов выяснилось, что когда на Зубра поступил 
>   донос, местный группенфюрер дело прекратил, сказав, что этого не может
>   быть. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)] [омонимия снята] ←…→
>   Он с пьяной бесцеремонностью доказывал, что, когда русские придут, Зубра повесят. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)] [омонимия снята] ←…→

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F7%F2%EE%20%EA%EE%E3%E4%E0&p=4

По сути это означает, что единого понимания правила тут нет.